# Multiple Models on a Single View/Template in Django

Tags: python, django

Trying to incorporate 2 models into my "season" view/template on my django site. Currently, I get the following as a ValueError "The view webapp.views.season didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." Not sure what I am doing wrong, but hoping someone can take a look.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Player, Season

def home(request):
    seasons = Season.objects.order_by('sid')
    return render(request, 'webapp/home.html', {'seasons': seasons})

def player(request, pk):
    player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'webapp/player.html', {'player': player})

def season(ListView, pk):
    model = Season
    template_name = 'webapp/season.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(season, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['players'] = Player.objects.all()
        return context

def seasons(request):
    seasons = Season.objects.order_by('sid')
    return render(request, 'webapp/seasons.html', {'seasons': seasons})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^player/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.player, name='player'),
    url(r'^season/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.season, name='season'),
    url(r'^seasons/$', views.seasons, name='seasons'),
]
```

It should be noted that I originally had a TypeError that said "season() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'" before I added the pk to the season argument. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views:`home`, `player` and `seasons` are [Function Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/), this is the old Django Views style. On the other hand, `ListView` is a  [Class Based View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/), a newer way to write views in Django. You are mixing both kind of views and that's a bad idea. No idea what your `season` view should do, but try something like:

```
def season(request, pk):
    season = get_object_or_404(Season, pk=pk) 
    return render(
        request, 
        'webapp/season.html',
        {'season': season, 'players': Player.objects.all()}
    )
```

Comment: So this gets it on the page, but displays for every season and not just the seasons they are attached to. How do I restrict it to just seasons that they player is part of? Currently, I have a third model that has the foreign keys for the Player and Season models. I assume I need to bridge them with this, but not sure how to code that up.

Answer (score 0):

In the url you need to call the class based view like, views.season.as_view()